# Android Facebook Login unique key

Tags: android, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I try to make a Facebook-Login on my app! And it works, perfectly.

But i would like to get a String or Number that is unique for User and App.
So that i can Authorize it on my own Server...

My actually way is:

- Andorid connect to Facebook
- Facebook send login facts to android
- Android send login state to my server

But for the last step i ned to get an unique value liek a number or String.
And the UserAccesToken change everytime the user is loged in...

Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the `id` field of the user obejct is for:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields

> The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps